# How should I test/spy this kind of event in backbone.marioentte

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, marionette

I am trying to implement a test (1) for this  module (2).
My purpose is to check if the collection is fetched when a particular event is triggered.
As you can see from my comment in (2) I get the message  `Expected spy restartPolling to have been called.`
The module works but the test fails. any ideas?

---

P.S.:

This question is related to this one [Expected a spy, but got Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053799/expected-a-spy-but-got-function/12058090#12058090)

---

(1)

```
// jasmine test module

describe('When onGivePoints is fired', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        spyOn(UsersBoardCollection.prototype, 'restartPolling').andCallThrough();
        app.vent.trigger('onGivePoints');
    });
    it('the board collection should be fetched', function () {
        expect(UsersBoardCollection.prototype.restartPolling).toHaveBeenCalled();
        // Expected spy restartPolling to have been called.
    });
});
```

---

(2)

```
// model view module
return Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new UserBoardCollection();
        this.collection.startPolling();
        app.vent.on('onGivePoints', this.collection.restartPolling);
    },
    // other code
});
```

---

(3)

```
// polling module

var poller = {
    restartPolling: function () {
        this.stopPolling();
        this.startPolling(options);
    },
    // other code
};
```

---

(4)

```
var UsersBoardCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // some code
});

_.extend(UsersBoardCollection.prototype, poller);

return UsersBoardCollection;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Marionette and I test the it a bit different. My idea is not to test, that when the event is fired on a real app that the function is called, cause this will be tested by Marionette developers.

I test that the event was binded to `app.vent`. Therefor I've create a spy on `app.vent.on` and fire the the function afterwards by myself:

```
spyOn(app.vent, 'on');
expect(app.vent.on.argsForCall[0][0]).toBe('onGivePoints')

app.vent.trigger.argsForCall[0][1]()
```