# Jasmine doesn't create spy on a function

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I've got following test: (**simplified**)

```
var request = require('request');
var routes = require('../routes.js');

describe('routes', function() {
  var req, res;

  beforeEach(function(){
    req = { headers: {}, url: 'http://127.0.0.1', params: {} };
    res = {
      sendFile: function() { return '' },
      render: function() { return '' },
      json: function() { return {} }
    };

    jasmine.createSpy(request, 'get')
  });

  it('should render static page', function() {
    routes.show(req, res);
    expect(request.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
});
```

and routes.js contents:

```
module.exports = {
  show: function(req, res) {
    request.get(apiUrl('v1/users/' + req.params.name), apiErrorsHandler(function(body) {
      res.render('users/show.jade', body);
    }, function() {
      res.json({});
    }));
  }
}
```

I'm using `gulp-jasmine` if it matters, but the problems happens anyway even when I use `jasmine-node`.

Each time I run a test I receive following error:

```
Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.
```

on line:

```
expect(request.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Do you have any idea why would that happen?

I've tried following solution: [Expected a spy, but got Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053799/expected-a-spy-but-got-function) but without success since `.get` is attached directly to a `request` so the reference was `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

jasmine.createSpy does not work quite like that..

What you want is to create a spy and assign it to the get property of the request object.

```
req = { headers: {}, url: 'http://127.0.0.1', params: {}, get: jasmine.createSpy('reqGetSpy')};
```