# Angular / Jasmine - Spying on scope function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have this code

```
it('should call checkConnectionToRoom when controller loads', function(done) {
    $scope.checkConnectionToRoom = function() {};

    spyOn($scope, 'checkConnectionToRoom').and.callThrough();

    roomController = $controller('RoomController', {$scope: $scope});

    expect($scope.checkConnectionToRoom).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    done();
  });
```

`$scope.checkConnectionToRoom` gets assigned when the controller loads. I'm trying to spy on it, so I am creating an empty function first. When the test runs I get: `Expected a spy, but got Function.`

How can I check `$scope.checkConnectionToRoom` gets called?

Comment: Is that AngularJS with $scope? If it is may need re-tagging.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053799/expected-a-spy-but-got-function

Comment: Thanks - retagged. I saw that answer, unfortunately none of the answers help in this case.

Comment: You have to show us your controller function.