# How to spy on localStorage methods with jasmine

Tags: javascript, firefox, jasmine, local-storage, karma-jasmine

Suppose I have a JavaScript code:

```
function modifiesLocalStorage() {
  var someBoolean = false;
  if(localStorage.getItem('someKey') === 'true'){
    localStorage.removeItem('someKey');
    someBoolean = true;
  }
  return someBoolean;
}
```

Then I have a jasmine test to test this method:

```
it('should return true', function(){
  spyOn(localStorage, 'removeItem');
  spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').and.returnValue('true');
  var returnValue = modifiesLocalStorage();
  expect(localStorage.getItem).toHaveBeenCalled(); //Error in this line
  expect(returnValue).toBeTruthy();
});
```

while executing this test I am getting following error:
`Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.`
What is this error and how do I fix it?

I am using Firefox 45.9.0 browser in headless mode to run the tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per this question's answer:
[Expected a spy, but got Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053799/expected-a-spy-but-got-function?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
We need to get into the actual method, which in this case is on the **proto**.

if I modify my tests like below, the test passes:

```
it('should return true', function(){
  spyOn(localStorage.__proto__, 'removeItem');
  spyOn(localStorage.__proto__, 'getItem').and.returnValue('true');
  var returnValue = modifiesLocalStorage();
  expect(localStorage.__proto__.getItem).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
  expect(returnValue).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Since `__proto__` is deprecated we can also use `Object.getPrototypeOf(localStorage)` to get the prototype of the `localStorage` object